# Can an audio be recorded and another audio file be played at the same time on USRobotics 56K Modem?

Tags: python, audio, audio-recording, telephony, modem

I have a USRobotics 56K Modem with USB connected to a linux system. I downloaded the sample python codes that can play and record audio through the modem on the following website [USRobotics Sample Code](https://iotbytes.wordpress.com/play-audio-file-on-phone-line-with-raspberry-pi/). I have tested them and the codes work flawlessly. However, for some reason I can't seem to find an answer to my question on the internet. So, I am asking here. Is it possible to record audio while playing different audio wave file at the same time on USRobotics modem using the following python codes?

**Playing Audio File:**

```
import serial
import time
import threading
import atexit
import sys
import re
import wave


analog_modem = serial.Serial()
analog_modem.port = "/dev/ttyACM0"
analog_modem.baudrate = 57600 #9600
analog_modem.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS #number of bits per bytes
analog_modem.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE #set parity check: no parity
analog_modem.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE #number of stop bits
analog_modem.timeout = 3            #non-block read
analog_modem.xonxoff = False     #disable software flow control
analog_modem.rtscts = False     #disable hardware (RTS/CTS) flow control
analog_modem.dsrdtr = False      #disable hardware (DSR/DTR) flow control
analog_modem.writeTimeout = 3     #timeout for write

# Used in global event listener
disable_modem_event_listener = True
RINGS_BEFORE_AUTO_ANSWER = 2


#=================================================================
# Initialize Modem
#=================================================================
def init_modem_settings():
# Opean Serial Port
try:
    analog_modem.open()
except:
    print "Error: Unable to open the Serial Port."
    sys.exit()


# Initialize
try:
    analog_modem.flushInput()
    analog_modem.flushOutput()

    # Test Modem connection, using basic AT command.
    if not exec_AT_cmd("AT"):
        print "Error: Unable to access the Modem"

    # reset to factory default.
    if not exec_AT_cmd("ATZ3"):
        print "Error: Unable reset to factory default"          
        
    # Display result codes in verbose form  
    if not exec_AT_cmd("ATV1"):
        print "Error: Unable set response in verbose form"  

    # Enable Command Echo Mode.
    if not exec_AT_cmd("ATE1"):
        print "Error: Failed to enable Command Echo Mode"       

    # Enable formatted caller report.
    if not exec_AT_cmd("AT+VCID=1"):
        print "Error: Failed to enable formatted caller report."

    # Enable formatted caller report.
    #if not exec_AT_cmd("AT+FCLASS=8"):
    #   print "Error: Failed to enable formatted caller report."


    analog_modem.flushInput()
    analog_modem.flushOutput()

except:
    print "Error: unable to Initialize the Modem"
    sys.exit()
#=================================================================


#================================================================= 
# Execute AT Commands on the Modem
#=================================================================
def exec_AT_cmd(modem_AT_cmd):
try:
    global disable_modem_event_listener
    disable_modem_event_listener = True

    cmd = modem_AT_cmd + "\r"
    analog_modem.write(cmd.encode())

    modem_response = analog_modem.readline()
    modem_response = modem_response + analog_modem.readline()

    print modem_response

    disable_modem_event_listener = False

    if ((modem_AT_cmd == "AT+VTX") or (modem_AT_cmd == "AT+VRX")) and ("CONNECT" in modem_response):
        # modem in TAD mode
        return True
    elif "OK" in modem_response:
        # Successful command execution
        return True
    else:
        # Failed command execution
        return False

except:
    disable_modem_event_listener = False
    print "Error: unable to write AT command to the modem..."
    return()
#=================================================================



#=================================================================
# Recover Serial Port
#=================================================================
def recover_from_error():
try:
    exec_AT_cmd("ATH")
except:
    pass

analog_modem.close()
init_modem_settings()

try:
    analog_modem.close()
except:
    pass

try:
    init_modem_settings()
except:
    pass

try:
    exec_AT_cmd("ATH")
except:
    pass

#=================================================================



#=================================================================
# Play wav file
#=================================================================
def play_audio():
print "Play Audio Msg - Start"

# Enter Voice Mode
if not exec_AT_cmd("AT+FCLASS=8"):
    print "Error: Failed to put modem into voice mode."
    return

# Compression Method and Sampling Rate Specifications
# Compression Method: 8-bit linear / Sampling Rate: 8000MHz
if not exec_AT_cmd("AT+VSM=128,8000"):
    print "Error: Failed to set compression method and sampling rate specifications."
    return

# Put modem into TAD Mode
if not exec_AT_cmd("AT+VLS=1"):
    print "Error: Unable put modem into TAD mode."
    return

# Put modem into TAD Mode
if not exec_AT_cmd("AT+VTX"):
    print "Error: Unable put modem into TAD mode."
    return

time.sleep(1)

# Play Audio File

global disable_modem_event_listener
disable_modem_event_listener = True

wf = wave.open('sample.wav','rb')
chunk = 1024

data = wf.readframes(chunk)
while data != '':
    analog_modem.write(data)
    data = wf.readframes(chunk)
    # You may need to change this sleep interval to smooth-out the audio
    time.sleep(.12)
wf.close()

#analog_modem.flushInput()
#analog_modem.flushOutput()

cmd = "<DLE><ETX>" + "\r"
analog_modem.write(cmd.encode())

# 2 Min Time Out
timeout = time.time() + 60*2 
while 1:
    modem_data = analog_modem.readline()
    if "OK" in modem_data:
        break
    if time.time() > timeout:
        break

disable_modem_event_listener = False

cmd = "ATH" + "\r"
analog_modem.write(cmd.encode())

print "Play Audio Msg - END"
return
#=================================================================

#=================================================================
# Modem Data Listener
#=================================================================
def read_data():
global disable_modem_event_listener
ring_data = ""

while 1:
    if not disable_modem_event_listener:
        modem_data = analog_modem.readline()
        if modem_data != "":
            print modem_data

            if "b" in modem_data.strip(chr(16)):
                print "b in modem data"
                print "b count:"
                print ((modem_data.strip(chr(16))).count("b"))
                print "total length:"
                print len(modem_data.strip(chr(16)))
                print modem_data
                
                if ((modem_data.strip(chr(16))).count("b")) == len(modem_data.strip(chr(16))):
                    print "all Bs in mode data"
                    #Terminate the call
                    if not exec_AT_cmd("ATH"):
                        print "Error: Busy Tone - Failed to terminate the call"
                        print "Trying to revoer the serial port"
                        recover_from_error()
                    else:
                        print "Busy Tone: Call Terminated"

            if "s" == modem_data.strip(chr(16)):
                #Terminate the call
                if not exec_AT_cmd("ATH"):
                    print "Error: Silence - Failed to terminate the call"
                    print "Trying to revoer the serial port"
                    recover_from_error()
                else:
                    print "Silence: Call Terminated"


            if ("RING" in modem_data) or ("DATE" in modem_data) or ("TIME" in modem_data) or ("NMBR" in modem_data):
                if "RING" in modem_data.strip(chr(16)):
                    ring_data = ring_data + modem_data
                    ring_count = ring_data.count("RING")
                    if ring_count == 1:
                        pass
                        print modem_data
                    elif ring_count == RINGS_BEFORE_AUTO_ANSWER:
                        ring_data = ""
                        play_audio()                            
 #=================================================================



 #=================================================================
 # Close the Serial Port
 #=================================================================
 def close_modem_port():
 try:
    exec_AT_cmd("ATH")
except:
    pass

try:
    if analog_modem.isOpen():
        analog_modem.close()
        print ("Serial Port closed...")
except:
    print "Error: Unable to close the Serial Port."
    sys.exit()
#=================================================================


init_modem_settings()

#Start a new thread to listen to modem data 
data_listener_thread = threading.Thread(target=read_data)
data_listener_thread.start()


# Close the Modem Port when the program terminates
atexit.register(close_modem_port)
```

**Recording Audio:**

```
import serial
import time
import threading
import atexit
import sys
import re
import wave
from datetime import datetime
import os
import fcntl
import subprocess


RINGS_BEFORE_AUTO_ANSWER = 2 #Must be greater than 1
MODEM_RESPONSE_READ_TIMEOUT = 120  #Time in Seconds (Default 120 Seconds)
MODEM_NAME = 'U.S. Robotics'    # Modem Manufacturer, For Ex: 'U.S. Robotics' if the 'lsusb' cmd output is similar to "Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0baf:0303 U.S. Robotics"


# Record Voice Mail Variables
REC_VM_MAX_DURATION = 120  # Time in Seconds

# Used in global event listener
disable_modem_event_listener = True

# Global Modem Object
analog_modem = serial.Serial()

audio_file_name = ''

#=================================================================
# Set COM Port settings
#=================================================================
def set_COM_port_settings(com_port):
analog_modem.port = com_port
analog_modem.baudrate = 57600 #9600 #115200
analog_modem.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS #number of bits per bytes
analog_modem.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE #set parity check: no parity
analog_modem.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE #number of stop bits
analog_modem.timeout = 3            #non-block read
analog_modem.xonxoff = False     #disable software flow control
analog_modem.rtscts = False     #disable hardware (RTS/CTS) flow control
analog_modem.dsrdtr = False      #disable hardware (DSR/DTR) flow control
analog_modem.writeTimeout = 3     #timeout for write
#=================================================================

#=================================================================
# Initialize Modem
#=================================================================
def detect_COM_port():

# List all the Serial COM Ports on Raspberry Pi
proc = subprocess.Popen(['ls /dev/tty[A-Za-z]*'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
com_ports = proc.communicate()[0]
com_ports_list = com_ports.split('\n')

# Find the right port associated with the Voice Modem
for com_port in com_ports_list:
    if 'tty' in com_port:
        #Try to open the COM Port and execute AT Command
        try:
            # Set the COM Port Settings
            set_COM_port_settings(com_port)
            analog_modem.open()
        except:
            print "Unable to open COM Port: " + com_port
            pass
        else:
            #Try to put Modem in Voice Mode
            if not exec_AT_cmd("AT+FCLASS=8", "OK"):
                print "Error: Failed to put modem into voice mode."
                if analog_modem.isOpen():
                    analog_modem.close()
            else:
                # Found the COM Port exit the loop
                print "Modem COM Port is: " + com_port
                analog_modem.flushInput()
                analog_modem.flushOutput()
                break
   #=================================================================



   #=================================================================
   # Initialize Modem
   #=================================================================
   def init_modem_settings():

   # Detect and Open the Modem Serial COM Port
   try:
    detect_COM_port()
   except:
    print "Error: Unable to open the Serial Port."
    sys.exit()

# Initialize the Modem
try:
    # Flush any existing input outout data from the buffers
    analog_modem.flushInput()
    analog_modem.flushOutput()

    # Test Modem connection, using basic AT command.
    if not exec_AT_cmd("AT"):
        print "Error: Unable to access the Modem"

    # reset to factory default.
    if not exec_AT_cmd("ATZ3"):
        print "Error: Unable reset to factory default"          
        
    # Display result codes in verbose form  
    if not exec_AT_cmd("ATV1"):
        print "Error: Unable set response in verbose form"  

    # Enable Command Echo Mode.
    if not exec_AT_cmd("ATE1"):
        print "Error: Failed to enable Command Echo Mode"       

    # Enable formatted caller report.
    if not exec_AT_cmd("AT+VCID=1"):
        print "Error: Failed to enable formatted caller report."
        
    # Flush any existing input outout data from the buffers
    analog_modem.flushInput()
    analog_modem.flushOutput()

except:
    print "Error: unable to Initialize the Modem"
    sys.exit() 
#=================================================================



#=================================================================
# Reset Modem
#=================================================================
def reset_USB_Device():

# Close the COM Port if it's open
try:
    if analog_modem.isOpen():
        analog_modem.close()
except:
    pass

# Equivalent of the _IO('U', 20) constant in the linux kernel.
USBDEVFS_RESET = ord('U') << (4*2) | 20
dev_path = ""

# Bases on 'lsusb' command, get the usb device path in the following format - 
# /dev/bus/usb/<busnum>/<devnum>
proc = subprocess.Popen(['lsusb'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out = proc.communicate()[0]
lines = out.split('\n')
for line in lines:
    if MODEM_NAME in line:
        parts = line.split()
        bus = parts[1]
        dev = parts[3][:3]
        dev_path = '/dev/bus/usb/%s/%s' % (bus, dev)

# Reset the USB Device
fd = os.open(dev_path, os.O_WRONLY)
try:
    fcntl.ioctl(fd, USBDEVFS_RESET, 0)
    print "Modem reset successful"
finally:
    os.close(fd)

# Re-initialize the Modem
init_modem_settings()
#=================================================================


#=================================================================
# Execute AT Commands at the Modem
#=================================================================
def exec_AT_cmd(modem_AT_cmd, expected_response="OK"):

global disable_modem_event_listener
disable_modem_event_listener = True

try:
    # Send command to the Modem
    analog_modem.write((modem_AT_cmd + "\r").encode())
    # Read Modem response
    execution_status = read_AT_cmd_response(expected_response)
    disable_modem_event_listener = False
    # Return command execution status
    return execution_status

except:
    disable_modem_event_listener = False
    print "Error: Failed to execute the command"
    return False        
#=================================================================


#=================================================================
# Read AT Command Response from the Modem
#=================================================================
def read_AT_cmd_response(expected_response="OK"):

# Set the auto timeout interval
start_time = datetime.now()

try:
    while 1:
        # Read Modem Data on Serial Rx Pin
        modem_response = analog_modem.readline()
        print modem_response
        # Recieved expected Response
        if expected_response == modem_response.strip(' \t\n\r' + chr(16)):
            return True
        # Failed to execute the command successfully
        elif "ERROR" in modem_response.strip(' \t\n\r' + chr(16)):
            return False
        # Timeout
        elif (datetime.now()-start_time).seconds > MODEM_RESPONSE_READ_TIMEOUT:
            return False

except:
    print "Error in read_modem_response function..."
    return False
#=================================================================

#=================================================================
# Recover Serial Port
#=================================================================
def recover_from_error():
# Stop Global Modem Event listener
global disable_modem_event_listener
disable_modem_event_listener = True

# Reset USB Device
reset_USB_Device()

# Start Global Modem Event listener
disable_modem_event_listener = False
#=================================================================

#=================================================================
# Read DTMF Digits
#=================================================================
def dtmf_digits(modem_data):
digits = ""
digit_list = re.findall('/(.+?)~', modem_data)
for d in digit_list:
    digits= digits + d[0]
return digits
#=================================================================



#=================================================================
# Record wav file (Voice Msg/Mail)
#=================================================================
def record_audio():
print "Record Audio Msg - Start"

# Enter Voice Mode
if not exec_AT_cmd("AT+FCLASS=8","OK"):
    print "Error: Failed to put modem into voice mode."
    return

# Set speaker volume to normal
if not exec_AT_cmd("AT+VGT=128","OK"):
    print "Error: Failed to set speaker volume to normal."
    return

# Compression Method and Sampling Rate Specifications
# Compression Method: 8-bit linear / Sampling Rate: 8000MHz
if not exec_AT_cmd("AT+VSM=128,8000","OK"):
    print "Error: Failed to set compression method and sampling rate specifications."
    return

# Disables silence detection (Value: 0)
if not exec_AT_cmd("AT+VSD=128,0","OK"):
    print "Error: Failed to disable silence detection."
    return

# Put modem into TAD Mode
if not exec_AT_cmd("AT+VLS=1","OK"):
    print "Error: Unable put modem into TAD mode."
    return

# Enable silence detection.
# Select normal silence detection sensitivity 
# and a silence detection interval of 5 s. 
if not exec_AT_cmd("AT+VSD=128,50","OK"):
    print "Error: Failed tp enable silence detection."
    return

# Play beep.
if not exec_AT_cmd("AT+VTS=[933,900,100]","OK"):
    print "Error: Failed to play 1.2 second beep."
    #return

# Select voice receive mode
if not exec_AT_cmd("AT+VRX","CONNECT"):
    print "Error: Unable put modem into voice receive mode."
    return

# Record Audio File

global disable_modem_event_listener
disable_modem_event_listener = True


# Set the auto timeout interval
start_time = datetime.now()
CHUNK = 1024
audio_frames = []

while 1:
    # Read audio data from the Modem
    audio_data = analog_modem.read(CHUNK)

    # Check if <DLE>b is in the stream
    if ((chr(16)+chr(98)) in audio_data):
        print "Busy Tone... Call will be disconnected."
        break

    # Check if <DLE>s is in the stream
    if ((chr(16)+chr(115)) in audio_data):
        print "Silence Detected... Call will be disconnected."
        break

    # Check if <DLE><ETX> is in the stream
    if (("<DLE><ETX>").encode() in audio_data):
        print "<DLE><ETX> Char Recieved... Call will be disconnected."
        break

    # Timeout
    elif ((datetime.now()-start_time).seconds) > REC_VM_MAX_DURATION:
        print "Timeout - Max recording limit reached."
        break

    # Add Audio Data to Audio Buffer
    audio_frames.append(audio_data)

global audio_file_name

# Save the Audio into a .wav file
wf = wave.open(audio_file_name, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(1)
wf.setsampwidth(1)
wf.setframerate(8000)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(audio_frames))
wf.close()

# Reset Audio File Name
audio_file_name = ''


# Send End of Voice Recieve state by passing "<DLE>!"
if not exec_AT_cmd((chr(16)+chr(33)),"OK"):
    print "Error: Unable to signal end of voice receive state"

# Hangup the Call
if not exec_AT_cmd("ATH","OK"):
    print "Error: Unable to hang-up the call"

# Enable global event listener
disable_modem_event_listener = False

print "Record Audio Msg - END"
return

#=================================================================

#=================================================================
# Data Listener
#=================================================================
def read_data():

global disable_modem_event_listener
ring_data = ""

while 1:

    if not disable_modem_event_listener:
        modem_data = analog_modem.readline()

    
        if modem_data != "":
            print modem_data

            # Check if <DLE>b is in the stream
            if (chr(16)+chr(98)) in modem_data:
                #Terminate the call
                if not exec_AT_cmd("ATH"):
                    print "Error: Busy Tone - Failed to terminate the call"
                    print "Trying to revoer the serial port"
                    recover_from_error()
                else:
                    print "Busy Tone: Call Terminated"
            
            # Check if <DLE>s is in the stream
            if (chr(16)+chr(115)) == modem_data:
                #Terminate the call
                if not exec_AT_cmd("ATH"):
                    print "Error: Silence - Failed to terminate the call"
                    print "Trying to revoer the serial port"
                    recover_from_error()
                else:
                    print "Silence: Call Terminated"


            if ("-s".encode() in modem_data) or (("<DLE>-s").encode() in modem_data):
                print "silence found during recording"
                analog_modem.write(("<DLE>-!" + "\r").encode())




            if ("RING" in modem_data) or ("DATE" in modem_data) or ("TIME" in modem_data) or ("NMBR" in modem_data):
                global audio_file_name
                if ("NMBR" in modem_data):
                    from_phone = (modem_data[5:]).strip()
                if ("DATE" in modem_data):
                    call_date =  (modem_data[5:]).strip()
                if ("TIME" in modem_data):
                    call_time =  (modem_data[5:]).strip() 
                if "RING" in modem_data.strip(chr(16)):
                    ring_data = ring_data + modem_data
                    ring_count = ring_data.count("RING")
                    if ring_count == 1:
                        pass
                    elif ring_count == RINGS_BEFORE_AUTO_ANSWER:
                        ring_data = ""
                        audio_file_name = from_phone + "_" + call_date + "_" + call_time + "_" + str(datetime.strftime(datetime.now(),"%S")) + ".wav"
                        from_phone = ''
                        call_date = ''
                        call_time = ''
                    
                        record_audio()

#=================================================================


#=================================================================
# Close the Serial Port
#=================================================================
def close_modem_port():

# Try to close any active call
try:
    exec_AT_cmd("ATH")
except:
    pass

# Close the Serial COM Port
try:
    if analog_modem.isOpen():
        analog_modem.close()
        print ("Serial Port closed...")
except:
    print "Error: Unable to close the Serial Port."
    sys.exit()
 #=================================================================


 # Main Function
 init_modem_settings()

 # Close the Modem Port when the program terminates
 atexit.register(close_modem_port)

# Monitor Modem Serial Port
read_data()
```

If so, could you please show me a working code.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Code you shared use modem in only one way; AT+VTX for Transmit,  AT+VRX for receive only. Choose one of code you shared to handle modem first, then use AT+VTR command to put modem send/receive mode.

After that, you should handle modem's transmit and receive buffer at the same time in a while loop; analog_modem.read(var) for recording and analog_modem.write(var) for playing. Also you may want to feed modem's transmit buffer with 0x80s at the 8K bytes per second if play file is shorter than your recording, otherwise modem will send to DTE, 'Transmit Buffer Underrun' codes.

Working code shown below. You may find 'AT Command Set for CX93010 chipset' in internet. All 'import' lines may not be necessary.

**phone-TX-RX.py**

```
## Python Ver: 3.9
##--- Inspired/Altered from original code belongs to:
##--- Author: Pradeep Singh
##--- Blog: https://iotbytes.wordpress.com/play-audio-file-on-phone-line-with-raspberry-pi/
##--- Date: 24th June 2018
##--- Version: 1.0
##--- Python Ver: 2.7
##--- Description: This python code will pick an incoming call and play an audio msg on the Phone line.
##------------------------------------------

import serial
import time
import threading
import atexit
import sys
import re
import wave
import os

line = serial.Serial()
line.port = "/dev/ttyACM0"
line.baudrate = 115200
line.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS #number of bits per bytes
line.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE #set parity check: no parity
line.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE #number of stop bits
line.timeout = 3            #non-block read
line.xonxoff = False     #disable software flow control
line.rtscts = False     #disable hardware (RTS/CTS) flow control
line.dsrdtr = False      #disable hardware (DSR/DTR) flow control
line.writeTimeout = 3     #timeout for write

# Used in global event listener
ANSWER_AFTER_RINGS = 1
AT_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT = 3
RING_TIMEOUT = 6  # timeout beetween two rings
MAX_REC_DURATION = 9    # max record duration

playRequested = False
playStarted = False
playFile = None
fileLen = 0
chunkCounter = 0
recRequested = False
recStarted = False
recTimeout = 0
recFile = None
audioFrames = []
ringCount = 0
ringTimeout = 0
modemResponse = bytes("", 'ascii')

# ACSII codes
DLE_CODE = chr(16).encode('ascii')      # Data Link Escape (DLE) code
ETX_CODE = chr(3).encode('ascii')       # End Transmission (ETX) code
CR_CODE = chr(13).encode('ascii')       # Carraige return
LF_CODE = chr(10).encode('ascii')       # Line feed
CRLF = (chr(13) + chr(10)).encode('ascii')
OK_STR = "OK\r\n".encode('ascii')
CONNECT_STR = "CONNECT\r\n".encode('ascii')
RING_STR = "RING\r\n".encode('ascii')

FACTORY_RESET = "ATZ\r\n".encode('ascii')
RESET_PROFILE = "ATZ0\r\n".encode('ascii')
GET_MODEM_PRODUCT_CODE = "ATI0\r\n".encode('ascii')
GET_MODEM_SETTINGS = "AT&V\r\n".encode('ascii')
ECHO_OFF = "ATE0\r\n".encode('ascii')
ECHO_ON = "ATE1\r\n".encode('ascii')
ENABLE_FORMATTED_CID = "AT+VCID=1\r\n".encode('ascii')
ENABLE_VERBOSE_CODES = "ATV1\r\n".encode('ascii')
DISABLE_SILENCE_DETECTION = "AT+VSD=0,0\r\n".encode('ascii')
ENABLE_SILENCE_DETECTION_5_SECS = "AT+VSD=0,50\r\n".encode('ascii')
ENABLE_SILENCE_DETECTION_10_SECS = "AT+VSD=0,100\r\n".encode('ascii')
ENTER_VOICE_MODE = "AT+FCLASS=8\r\n".encode('ascii')
ENTER_VOICE_RECIEVE_STATE = "AT+VRX\r\n".encode('ascii')
ENTER_VOICE_TRANSMIT_STATE = "AT+VTX\r\n".encode('ascii')
ENTER_VOICE_TRANSMIT_RECIEVE_STATE = "AT+VTR\r\n".encode('ascii')   # Start Voice Transmission and Reception (Voice Duplex)
SEND_VOICE_TONE_BEEP = "AT+VTS=[900,900,120]\r\n".encode('ascii')   # 1.2 second beep
GET_VOICE_COMPRESSION_SETTING = "AT+VSM?\r\n".encode('ascii')
GET_VOICE_COMPRESSION_OPTIONS = "AT+VSM=?\r\n".encode('ascii')
SET_VOICE_COMPRESSION = "AT+VSM=1,8000,0,0\r\n".encode('ascii')  # 1 = 8-bit unsigned pcm, 8.0 kHz
LINE_OFF_HOOK = "AT+VLS=1\r\n".encode('ascii')  # DCE off-hook, connected to telco
LINE_ON_HOOK = "AT+VLS=0\r\n".encode('ascii')   # DCE on-hook
TERMINATE_CALL = "ATH\r\n".encode('ascii')

# Modem DLE shielded codes - DCE to DTE modem data
DCE_ANSWER_TONE = (chr(16) + chr(97)).encode('ascii')          # <DLE>-a
DCE_BUSY_TONE = (chr(16) + chr(98)).encode('ascii')            # <DLE>-b
DCE_FAX_CALLING_TONE = (chr(16) + chr(99)).encode('ascii')     # <DLE>-c
DCE_DIAL_TONE = (chr(16) + chr(100)).encode('ascii')           # <DLE>-d
DCE_DATA_CALLING_TONE = (chr(16) + chr(101)).encode('ascii')   # <DLE>-e
DCE_LINE_REVERSAL = (chr(16) + chr(108)).encode('ascii')       # <DLE>-l
DCE_PHONE_ON_HOOK = (chr(16) + chr(104)).encode('ascii')       # <DLE>-h
DCE_PHONE_OFF_HOOK = (chr(16) + chr(72)).encode('ascii')       # <DLE>-H
DCE_PHONE_OFF_HOOK2 = (chr(16) + chr(80)).encode('ascii')      # <DLE>-P
DCE_QUIET_DETECTED = (chr(16) + chr(113)).encode('ascii')      # <DLE>-q
DCE_RING = (chr(16) + chr(82)).encode('ascii')                 # <DLE>-R
DCE_SILENCE_DETECTED = (chr(16) + chr(115)).encode('ascii')    # <DLE>-s
DCE_TX_BUFFER_UNDERRUN = (chr(16) + chr(117)).encode('ascii')  # <DLE>-u
DCE_END_VOICE_DATA_TX = (chr(16) + chr(3)).encode('ascii')     # <DLE><ETX>

# System DLE shielded codes (single DLE) - DTE to DCE commands (used by USR 5637 modem)
DTE_RAISE_VOLUME = (chr(16) + chr(117)).encode('ascii')           # <DLE>u
DTE_LOWER_VOLUME = (chr(16) + chr(100)).encode('ascii')           # <DLE>d
DTE_END_VOICE_DATA_RX = (chr(16) + chr(33)).encode('ascii')       # <DLE>!
DTE_END_VOICE_DATA_TX = (chr(16) + chr(3)).encode('ascii')        # <DLE><ETX>
DTE_END_VOICE_DATA_TX_RX = (chr(16) + chr(94)).encode('ascii')    # <DLE>^
DTE_CLEAR_TRANSMIT_BUFFER = (chr(16) + chr(24)).encode('ascii')   # <DLE><CAN>
#=================================================================
# Initialize Modem
#=================================================================
def initialize_modem():
    # Opean Serial Port
    try:
        line.open()
        print ("Serial port open")
    except Exception as err:
        print(f"Unexpected {err=}, {type(err)=}")
        print ("Error: Unable to open the Serial Port.")
        sys.exit()

    # Initialize
    try:
        line.reset_input_buffer()
        line.reset_output_buffer()

        # hang-up if opened
        send(TERMINATE_CALL, OK_STR)
        # reset to factory default.
        send(FACTORY_RESET, OK_STR)
        # Disable Command Echo Mode.
        send(ECHO_OFF, OK_STR)
        # Display result codes in verbose form  
        send(ENABLE_VERBOSE_CODES, OK_STR)
        # Enable formatted caller report.
        send(ENABLE_FORMATTED_CID, OK_STR)

    except Exception as err:
        print(f"Unexpected {err=}, {type(err)=}")
        print ("Error: unable to Initialize the Modem")
        sys.exit()
#=================================================================

#=================================================================
# Execute AT Commands on the Modem
#=================================================================
def send(cmd, resp):
    global modemResponse
    result = False

    try:
        # Send command to the Modem
        line.write(cmd)

        print ("sent >:", cmd)
        modemResponse = bytes("", 'ascii')

        if (resp == ""):
            return

        timeout = time.time() + AT_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT
        while (time.time() < timeout):
            if (line.in_waiting != 0): # if response
                modemResponse += line.read(line.in_waiting)
            if (resp in modemResponse):
                result = True
                break

        print ("rcvd <:", modemResponse)
        modemResponse = bytes("", 'ascii')

        # Failed command execution
        if (result == False):
            print ("Modem AT Command timeout")
            sys.exit()
    except Exception as err:
        print(f"Unexpected {err=}, {type(err)=}")
        print ("Error: unable to write AT command to the modem: ", cmd)
        sys.exit()
#=================================================================

#=================================================================
# Set Modem Voice Mode
#=================================================================
def set_voice_mod():
    # Enter Voice Mode
    send(ENTER_VOICE_MODE, OK_STR)
    # Compression Method and Sampling Rate Specifications
    # Compression Method: Unsigned PCM / Sampling Rate: 8000MHz
    send(SET_VOICE_COMPRESSION, OK_STR)
    # Open phone line
    send(LINE_OFF_HOOK, OK_STR)
    # Enable silence detection.
    # Select normal silence detection sensitivity and a silence detection interval of 5 s. 
    send(ENABLE_SILENCE_DETECTION_5_SECS, OK_STR)
    # Put modem into voice transmit receive mode
    send(ENTER_VOICE_TRANSMIT_RECIEVE_STATE, CONNECT_STR)

#=================================================================
# Play wav file
#=================================================================
def handle_play():
    global playRequested, playStarted, playFile, fileLen, chunkCounter
    CHUNK = 256

    if (playRequested):
        if (not playStarted):
            # Play Audio File
            playFile = wave.open('sample.wav','rb')
            fileLen = playFile.getnframes() / CHUNK
            chunkCounter = 0
            playStarted = True
            print ("Play Audio Msg - Start")
        else:
            if (chunkCounter < fileLen):
                if (line.out_waiting < CHUNK):
                    line.write(playFile.readframes(CHUNK))
                    chunkCounter = chunkCounter + 1
            else:
                playFile.close()
                playStarted = False
                print ("Play Audio Msg - End")

#=================================================================

def handle_record():
    global recRequested, recStarted, recTimeout, recFile, audioFrames

    if (recRequested):
        if (not recStarted):
            # Play Audio File
            recFile = wave.open('record.wav', 'wb')
            recFile.setnchannels(1)
            recFile.setsampwidth(1)
            recFile.setframerate(8000)
            recTimeout = time.time() + MAX_REC_DURATION
            audioFrames = []
            print ("Record Audio Msg - Start")
            recStarted = True
        else:
            if (line.in_waiting > 0):
                # Read audio data from the Modem
                audio_data = line.read(line.in_waiting)
                # Check if <DLE>b is in the stream
                if (DCE_BUSY_TONE in audio_data):
                    print ("Busy Tone... Call will be disconnected.")
                # Check if <DLE>s is in the stream
                elif (DCE_SILENCE_DETECTED in audio_data):
                    print ("Silence Detected... Call will be disconnected.")
                # Check if <DLE><ETX> is in the stream
                elif (DCE_END_VOICE_DATA_TX in audio_data):
                    print ("<DLE><ETX> Char Recieved... Call will be disconnected.")
                else:
                    # Add Audio Data to Audio Buffer
                    audioFrames.append(audio_data)
            elif (time.time() > recTimeout):
                # Save the Audio into a .wav file
                recFile.writeframes(b''.join(audioFrames))
                recFile.close()
                recStarted = False
                print ("Record Audio Msg - End")


#=================================================================

#=================================================================
# Modem Data Listener
#=================================================================
def handle_line():
    global playRequested, recRequested, playStarted, recStarted, modemResponse, ringCount, ringTimeout

    # print ("Waiting for ", str(ANSWER_AFTER_RINGS), " ring(s)")
    if (playRequested or recRequested):
        if (playRequested and (not playStarted)):   # play ended
            playRequested = False
        if (recRequested and (not recStarted)): # record ended
            recRequested = False
        if ((not playStarted) and (not recStarted)):    # play and record ended, line idle
            send(DTE_END_VOICE_DATA_TX_RX, DCE_END_VOICE_DATA_TX)
            send(DCE_END_VOICE_DATA_TX, OK_STR)
            #Terminate the call
            print ("Hang-up: Call ended")
            send(TERMINATE_CALL, OK_STR)
        return
    if (line.in_waiting != 0):
        modemResponse += line.read(line.in_waiting)
        if (len(modemResponse) != 0):
            print ("rcvd <:", modemResponse)
            if (DCE_BUSY_TONE in modemResponse): #3 busy tone
                #Terminate the call
                print ("Busy Tone: Call Terminated")
                send(TERMINATE_CALL, OK_STR)
            elif (DCE_SILENCE_DETECTED in modemResponse): #3 silence
                #Terminate the call
                print ("Silence: Call Terminated")
                send(TERMINATE_CALL, OK_STR)
            elif (RING_STR in modemResponse): # or ("DATE" in modemResponse) or ("TIME" in modemResponse) or ("NMBR" in modemResponse):
                modemResponse = bytes("", 'ascii')
                ringTimeout = time.time() + RING_TIMEOUT
                ringCount = ringCount + 1
                if (ringCount == ANSWER_AFTER_RINGS):
                    print ("Ring: Call Started")
                    ringTimeout = 0
                    ringCount = 0
                    set_voice_mod()
                    playRequested = True
                    recRequested = True

    if ((ringTimeout != 0) and (time.time() > ringTimeout)):  # new ring did not come before play_audio
        ringTimeout = 0
        ringCount = 0
        modemResponse = bytes("", 'ascii')

#=================================================================

#=================================================================
# Close the Serial Port
#=================================================================
def close_modem_port():
    send(TERMINATE_CALL, OK_STR)

    try:
        if line.isOpen():
            line.close()
            print ("Serial Port closed...")
    except Exception as err:
        print(f"Unexpected {err=}, {type(err)=}")
        print ("Error: Unable to close the Serial Port.")
        sys.exit()
#=================================================================

try:
    os.remove('record.wav')
except OSError:
    pass

initialize_modem()
atexit.register(close_modem_port)

while(True):
    handle_line()
    handle_play()
    handle_record()
```

And code below with one handler for record and play.

**phone-SingleHandler.py**

```
# Python Ver: 3.9
##--- Inspired/Altered from original code belongs to:
##--- Author: Pradeep Singh
##--- Blog: https://iotbytes.wordpress.com/play-audio-file-on-phone-line-with-raspberry-pi/
##--- Date: 24th June 2018
##--- Version: 1.0
##--- Python Ver: 2.7
##--- Description: This python code will pick an incoming call and play an audio msg on the Phone line.
##------------------------------------------

import serial
import time
import threading
import atexit
import sys
import re
import wave
import os

line = serial.Serial()
line.port = "/dev/ttyACM0"
line.baudrate = 115200
line.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS #number of bits per bytes
line.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE #set parity check: no parity
line.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE #number of stop bits
line.timeout = 3            #non-block read
line.xonxoff = False     #disable software flow control
line.rtscts = False     #disable hardware (RTS/CTS) flow control
line.dsrdtr = False      #disable hardware (DSR/DTR) flow control
line.writeTimeout = 3     #timeout for write

# Used in global event listener
ANSWER_AFTER_RINGS = 1
AT_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT = 3
RING_TIMEOUT = 6  # timeout beetween two rings
MAX_REC_DURATION = 9    # max record duration

playStarted = False
playFile = None
fileLen = 0
chunkCounter = 0
recStarted = False
recTimeout = 0
recFile = None
audioFrames = []
lineRXbuffer = []
lineTXbuffer = []
ringCount = 0
ringTimeout = 0
modemResponse = bytes("", 'ascii')

# ACSII codes
DLE_CODE = chr(16).encode('ascii')      # Data Link Escape (DLE) code
ETX_CODE = chr(3).encode('ascii')       # End Transmission (ETX) code
CR_CODE = chr(13).encode('ascii')       # Carraige return
LF_CODE = chr(10).encode('ascii')       # Line feed
CRLF = (chr(13) + chr(10)).encode('ascii')
OK_STR = "OK\r\n".encode('ascii')
CONNECT_STR = "CONNECT\r\n".encode('ascii')
RING_STR = "RING\r\n".encode('ascii')

FACTORY_RESET = "ATZ\r\n".encode('ascii')
RESET_PROFILE = "ATZ0\r\n".encode('ascii')
GET_MODEM_PRODUCT_CODE = "ATI0\r\n".encode('ascii')
GET_MODEM_SETTINGS = "AT&V\r\n".encode('ascii')
ECHO_OFF = "ATE0\r\n".encode('ascii')
ECHO_ON = "ATE1\r\n".encode('ascii')
ENABLE_FORMATTED_CID = "AT+VCID=1\r\n".encode('ascii')
ENABLE_VERBOSE_CODES = "ATV1\r\n".encode('ascii')
DISABLE_SILENCE_DETECTION = "AT+VSD=0,0\r\n".encode('ascii')
ENABLE_SILENCE_DETECTION_5_SECS = "AT+VSD=0,50\r\n".encode('ascii')
ENABLE_SILENCE_DETECTION_10_SECS = "AT+VSD=0,100\r\n".encode('ascii')
ENTER_VOICE_MODE = "AT+FCLASS=8\r\n".encode('ascii')
ENTER_VOICE_RECIEVE_STATE = "AT+VRX\r\n".encode('ascii')
ENTER_VOICE_TRANSMIT_STATE = "AT+VTX\r\n".encode('ascii')
ENTER_VOICE_TRANSMIT_RECIEVE_STATE = "AT+VTR\r\n".encode('ascii')   # Start Voice Transmission and Reception (Voice Duplex)
SEND_VOICE_TONE_BEEP = "AT+VTS=[900,900,120]\r\n".encode('ascii')   # 1.2 second beep
GET_VOICE_COMPRESSION_SETTING = "AT+VSM?\r\n".encode('ascii')
GET_VOICE_COMPRESSION_OPTIONS = "AT+VSM=?\r\n".encode('ascii')
SET_VOICE_COMPRESSION = "AT+VSM=1,8000,0,0\r\n".encode('ascii')  # 1 = 8-bit unsigned pcm, 8.0 kHz
LINE_OFF_HOOK = "AT+VLS=1\r\n".encode('ascii')  # DCE off-hook, connected to telco
LINE_ON_HOOK = "AT+VLS=0\r\n".encode('ascii')   # DCE on-hook
TERMINATE_CALL = "ATH\r\n".encode('ascii')


# Modem DLE shielded codes - DCE to DTE modem data
DCE_ANSWER_TONE = (chr(16) + chr(97)).encode('ascii')          # <DLE>-a
DCE_BUSY_TONE = (chr(16) + chr(98)).encode('ascii')            # <DLE>-b
DCE_FAX_CALLING_TONE = (chr(16) + chr(99)).encode('ascii')     # <DLE>-c
DCE_DIAL_TONE = (chr(16) + chr(100)).encode('ascii')           # <DLE>-d
DCE_DATA_CALLING_TONE = (chr(16) + chr(101)).encode('ascii')   # <DLE>-e
DCE_LINE_REVERSAL = (chr(16) + chr(108)).encode('ascii')       # <DLE>-l
DCE_PHONE_ON_HOOK = (chr(16) + chr(104)).encode('ascii')       # <DLE>-h
DCE_PHONE_OFF_HOOK = (chr(16) + chr(72)).encode('ascii')       # <DLE>-H
DCE_PHONE_OFF_HOOK2 = (chr(16) + chr(80)).encode('ascii')      # <DLE>-P
DCE_QUIET_DETECTED = (chr(16) + chr(113)).encode('ascii')      # <DLE>-q
DCE_RING = (chr(16) + chr(82)).encode('ascii')                 # <DLE>-R
DCE_SILENCE_DETECTED = (chr(16) + chr(115)).encode('ascii')    # <DLE>-s
DCE_TX_BUFFER_UNDERRUN = (chr(16) + chr(117)).encode('ascii')  # <DLE>-u
DCE_END_VOICE_DATA_TX = (chr(16) + chr(3)).encode('ascii')     # <DLE><ETX>


# System DLE shielded codes (single DLE) - DTE to DCE commands (used by USR 5637 modem)
DTE_RAISE_VOLUME = (chr(16) + chr(117)).encode('ascii')           # <DLE>u
DTE_LOWER_VOLUME = (chr(16) + chr(100)).encode('ascii')           # <DLE>d
DTE_END_VOICE_DATA_RX = (chr(16) + chr(33)).encode('ascii')       # <DLE>!
DTE_END_VOICE_DATA_TX = (chr(16) + chr(3)).encode('ascii')        # <DLE><ETX>
DTE_END_VOICE_DATA_TX_RX = (chr(16) + chr(94)).encode('ascii')    # <DLE>^
DTE_CLEAR_TRANSMIT_BUFFER = (chr(16) + chr(24)).encode('ascii')   # <DLE><CAN>
#=================================================================
# Initialize Modem
#=================================================================
def initialize_modem():
    # Opean Serial Port
    try:
        line.open()
        print ("Serial port open")
    except Exception as err:
        print(f"Unexpected {err=}, {type(err)=}")
        print ("Error: Unable to open the Serial Port.")
        sys.exit()

    # Initialize
    try:
        line.reset_input_buffer()
        line.reset_output_buffer()

        # hang-up if opened
        send(TERMINATE_CALL, OK_STR)
        # reset to factory default.
        send(FACTORY_RESET, OK_STR)
        # Disable Command Echo Mode.
        send(ECHO_OFF, OK_STR)
        # Display result codes in verbose form  
        send(ENABLE_VERBOSE_CODES, OK_STR)
        # Enable formatted caller report.
        send(ENABLE_FORMATTED_CID, OK_STR)

    except Exception as err:
        print(f"Unexpected {err=}, {type(err)=}")
        print ("Error: unable to Initialize the Modem")
        sys.exit()
#=================================================================

#=================================================================
# Execute AT Commands on the Modem
#=================================================================
def send(cmd, resp):
    global modemResponse
    result = False

    try:
        # Send command to the Modem
        line.write(cmd)

        print ("sent >:", cmd)
        modemResponse = bytes("", 'ascii')

        if (resp == ""):
            return

        timeout = time.time() + AT_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT
        while (time.time() < timeout):
            if (line.in_waiting != 0): # if response
                modemResponse += line.read(line.in_waiting)
            if (resp in modemResponse):
                result = True
                break

        print ("rcvd <:", modemResponse)
        modemResponse = bytes("", 'ascii')

        # Failed command execution
        if (result == False):
            print ("Modem AT Command timeout")
            sys.exit()
    except Exception as err:
        print(f"Unexpected {err=}, {type(err)=}")
        print ("Error: unable to write AT command to the modem: ", cmd)
        sys.exit()
#=================================================================

#=================================================================
# Set Modem Voice Mode
#=================================================================
def set_voice_mod():
    # Enter Voice Mode
    send(ENTER_VOICE_MODE, OK_STR)
    # Compression Method and Sampling Rate Specifications
    # Compression Method: Unsigned PCM / Sampling Rate: 8000MHz
    send(SET_VOICE_COMPRESSION, OK_STR)
    # Open phone line
    send(LINE_OFF_HOOK, OK_STR)
    # Enable silence detection.
    # Select normal silence detection sensitivity and a silence detection interval of 5 s. 
    send(ENABLE_SILENCE_DETECTION_5_SECS, OK_STR)
    # Put modem into voice transmit receive mode
    send(ENTER_VOICE_TRANSMIT_RECIEVE_STATE, CONNECT_STR)

#=================================================================
# Modem Data Listener
#=================================================================
def handle_line():
    CHUNK = 256
    global recStarted, recTimeout, recFile, audioFrames, playStarted, playFile, fileLen, chunkCounter, modemResponse, ringCount, ringTimeout

    if (playStarted or recStarted):
        if (playStarted):
            if (chunkCounter < fileLen):
                if (line.out_waiting < CHUNK):
                    line.write(playFile.readframes(CHUNK))
                    chunkCounter = chunkCounter + 1
            else:
                playFile.close()
                playStarted = False
                print ("Play Audio Msg - End")

        if (recStarted):
            if (line.in_waiting > 0):
                # Read audio data from the Modem
                audio_data = line.read(line.in_waiting)
                # Check if <DLE>b is in the stream
                if (DCE_BUSY_TONE in audio_data):
                    print ("Busy Tone... Call will be disconnected.")
                # Check if <DLE>s is in the stream
                elif (DCE_SILENCE_DETECTED in audio_data):
                    print ("Silence Detected... Call will be disconnected.")
                # Check if <DLE><ETX> is in the stream
                elif (DCE_END_VOICE_DATA_TX in audio_data):
                    print ("<DLE><ETX> Char Recieved... Call will be disconnected.")
                else:
                    # Add Audio Data to Audio Buffer
                    audioFrames.append(audio_data)  # .strip(' \t\n\r' + chr(16) + chr(3))
                    recFile.writeframes(b''.join(audioFrames))
                    audioFrames = []

            if (time.time() > recTimeout):
                # Save the Audio into a .wav file
                recFile.close()
                recStarted = False
                # Send End of Voice Recieve state by passing "<DLE>^"
                send(DTE_END_VOICE_DATA_TX_RX, DCE_END_VOICE_DATA_TX)
                send(DCE_END_VOICE_DATA_TX, OK_STR)
                print ("Record Audio Msg - End")
                #Terminate the call
                send(TERMINATE_CALL, OK_STR)
                print ("Hang-up: Call ended")
        return

    # lineRXbuffer = 
    if (line.in_waiting > 0):
        modemResponse += line.read(line.in_waiting)
        if (len(modemResponse) != 0):
            print ("rcvd <:", modemResponse)
            if (DCE_BUSY_TONE in modemResponse): #3 busy tone
                #Terminate the call
                print ("Busy Tone: Call Terminated")
                send(TERMINATE_CALL, OK_STR)
            elif (DCE_SILENCE_DETECTED in modemResponse): #3 silence
                #Terminate the call
                print ("Silence: Call Terminated")
                send(TERMINATE_CALL, OK_STR)
            elif (RING_STR in modemResponse): # or ("DATE" in modemResponse) or ("TIME" in modemResponse) or ("NMBR" in modemResponse):
                modemResponse = bytes("", 'ascii')
                ringTimeout = time.time() + RING_TIMEOUT
                ringCount = ringCount + 1
                if (ringCount == ANSWER_AFTER_RINGS):
                    print ("Ring: Call Started")
                    ringTimeout = 0
                    ringCount = 0
                    set_voice_mod()
                    # Play Audio File
                    playFile = wave.open('sample.wav','rb')
                    fileLen = playFile.getnframes() / CHUNK
                    chunkCounter = 0
                    playStarted = True
                    print ("Play Audio Msg - Start")
                    # Record Audio File
                    recFile = wave.open('record.wav', 'wb')
                    recFile.setnchannels(1)
                    recFile.setsampwidth(1)
                    recFile.setframerate(8000)
                    recTimeout = time.time() + MAX_REC_DURATION
                    audioFrames = []
                    print ("Record Audio Msg - Start")
                    recStarted = True

    if ((ringTimeout != 0) and (time.time() > ringTimeout)):  # new ring did not come before play_audio
        ringTimeout = 0
        ringCount = 0
        modemResponse = bytes("", 'ascii')

#=================================================================

#=================================================================
# Close the Serial Port
#=================================================================
def close_modem_port():
    send(TERMINATE_CALL, OK_STR)

    try:
        if line.is_open:
            line.close()
            print ("Serial Port closed...")
    except Exception as err:
        print(f"Unexpected {err=}, {type(err)=}")
        print ("Error: Unable to close the Serial Port.")
        sys.exit()
#=================================================================

try:
    os.remove('record.wav')
except OSError:
    pass

initialize_modem()
atexit.register(close_modem_port)

while(True):
    handle_line()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```